# memoization not working as expected

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am new to algorithms and so I was experimenting with several possibilities of algorithms, specially memoisation

I have a simple Fibonacci series recursive function using memoisation

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not args in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.f(*args)
            print args
        print self.memo
        return self.memo[args]

def fibbo3(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    elif n==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return fibbo3(n-1) + fibbo3(n-2)

m = Memoize(fibbo3)

m(4)
print "check the memo"
print m.memo

(4,)
{(4,): 3}
check the memo
{(4,): 3}
```

But if I call

```
fibbo3 = Memoize(fibbo3)
fibbo3(4)
print 'ckeck the memo'
fibbo3.memo

(1,)
{(1,): 1}
(0,)
{(0,): 0, (1,): 1}
(2,)
{(2,): 1, (0,): 0, (1,): 1}
{(2,): 1, (0,): 0, (1,): 1}
(3,)
{(2,): 1, (0,): 0, (3,): 2, (1,): 1}
{(2,): 1, (0,): 0, (3,): 2, (1,): 1}
(4,)
{(2,): 1, (0,): 0, (3,): 2, (1,): 1, (4,): 3}
ckeck the memo
Out[524]:
{(0,): 0, (1,): 1, (2,): 1, (3,): 2, (4,): 3}
```

I see the entire memoised dictionary. WHy does changing the name of variable from 'm' to 'fibbo3' (i.e the name of the function) results in such a behavior

Answer (score 4):

The reason is `m = Memoize(fibbo3)` does not affect the recursive references to `fibbo3` made from `fibbo3` whereas `fibbo3 = Memoize(fibbo3)` does.

You might also want to consider using one of the [memoizing decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) in the Python Decorator Library.

Comment: "The reason is m = Memoize(fibbo3) does not affect the recursive references to fibbo3 made from  fibbo3 whereas fibbo3 = Memoize(fibbo3) does"............Could you pls tell .Why does it happen like that?

Comment: Because inside the fibbo3 function, it does not know that you are going to Memoize it later.  You can rewrite that line as ``return Memoize(fibbo3(n-1)) + Memorize(fibbo3(n-2))``